# django : get base variables before view starts work

Tags: django, view, decorator

I have such a question, i have googled a lot, read about `decorators` and `middleware`, but i didnt catch how to solve my question better.

i have base template `base.html` and templates `template1.html` and `template2.html` which are extended of `base.html`.

`base.html` has some general block, which is needed in `template1.html` and `template2.html`.
this block is with dinamic data, so i have to get data for this block in each view and then render template.

for example i have 2 `views` :

```
@render_to("template1.html")
def fun_1(request):
data = getGeneralData()
#...getting other data
return {
        "data" : data,
        "other" : other_data,
}

@render_to("template2.html")
def fun_2(request):
data = getGeneralData()
#...getting other data
return {
        "data" : data,
        "other2" : other_data2,
}
```

So general i need this `getGeneralData` in all of my `views`, have i to call `getGeneralData()` function in every my view or can i make any function which will get `general_data` and render it to template before any view gets its own data ?

Can you please provide me an example of code or give me a good link how to do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will recommend you to write your own [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) and return required context data from there.

Example :

custom_context_processor.py

```
def ctx_getGeneralData(request):
    ctx = {}
    ctx['data'] = getGeneralData()
    return ctx
```

In settings file, update `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` to have `'custom_context_processor.ctx_getGeneralData'`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Django's class-based views? They're a little hard to use initially, but they make things like this very simple. Here's how I'd rewrite your function-based views using class-based views:

```
# TemplateView is a generic class based view that simply
# renders a template.
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


# Let's start by defining a mixin that we can mix into any view that
# needs the result of getGeneralData() in its template context.


class GeneralContextDataMixin(object):
    """
    Adds the result of calling getGeneralData() to the context of whichever
    view it is mixed into.
    """

    get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Django calls get_context_data() on all CBVs that render templates.
        It returns a dictionary containing the data you want to add to
        your template context.
        """
        context = super(GeneralContextDataMixin, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['data'] = getGeneralData()
        return context


# Now we can inherit from this mixin wherever we need the results of
# getGeneralData(). Note the order of inheritance; it's important.


class View1(GeneralContextDataMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'template1.html'


class View2(GeneralContextDataMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'template2.html'
```

Of course, you could also write your own context processor as Rohan said. In fact, that's what I'd suggest you do if you want to add this data to *all* your views.

Whatever you end up doing, I would urge you to look into class-based views. They make many repetitive tasks very easy.

Further reading:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/